# Populate two select lists with one function / jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

If I have two select lists, can I populate them both with the same function? Somthing like this. This doesnt seem to be working though.

```
        function populateSel(){
         jQuery("#selectListOne, #selectListTwo")
          .append('<option value=""></option>')
          .append('<option value="Mr."></option>')
          .append('<option value="Ms."></option>')  
          .append('<option value="Mrs."></option>') 
          .append('<option value="Dr."></option>')  
          .append('<option value="Prof."></option>')           
        }
```

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yMnbF/ Your issue may be that you've not given the `option` elements any text, or there are errors elsewhere. Check the console.

Comment: Hmmm... cheers. I'll double check everything again.

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified the display label for the options, other than that it looks fine

```
jQuery("#selectListOne, #selectListTwo")
.append('<option value=""></option>')
.append('<option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>')
.append('<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>')  
.append('<option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>') 
.append('<option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>')  
.append('<option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VVTgS/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function populateSel(){
         jQuery("#selectListOne, #selectListTwo")
          .append('<option value=""></option><option value="Mr."></option><option value="Ms."></option><option value="Mrs."></option><option value="Dr."></option><option value="Prof."></option>');           
        }
```

Thanks and regrads,

Comment: Although this is a better way to append the options, it produces the same result